# Can KAA be used for embedded board WITHOUT any OS?

Tags: kaa

My use case is to send image to **Amazon AWS cloud** using KAA.
Embedded board which I use does not have any operating system. I am trying to use C SDK for my cortex M4 based board. But it **does not have any OS**.

For which platform option do I need to compile C SDK?
Will it be possible to use this generated KAA library to place on embedded board and send data to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kaa C SDK does support running on platforms without any OS.

Examples:

- [ESP8266](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl/esp8266)
- [TI CC3200](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl/cc32xx) (Cortex-M4 board)

If you want to run Kaa on a different platform, you should implement a new platform abstraction. You can find reference implementations in the [client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl) directory.